# How to make Excel VBA loop until it reaches the end of data

Tags: excel, loops, automation, spreadsheet

I am a novice to VBA, and I would greatly appreciate your help. I need to automate a task that I am doing as a part of my research.

I have two Workbooks, one with multiple spreadsheets (one for each sound measurement, its name is Matlab Contours_Extracted_20170815.xlsx), and another one, where I need to consolidate the first column from each spreadsheet of the first one (it's called Mat-lab Contours consolidated.xlx).

I managed to get as far as automatic one-by-one copy and paste process, and it is working, but I would like it to go until it hits the end of a document (and it is not a set number of sheets).

Below is the code that I have, and here are my questions:

1. How do I loop it, so it goes through all the spreadsheets until the end by itself?
2. How do I make it start with the first one (I had it, but I lost it now, and it jumps straight to Sheet+1). Not a huge issue, but would be most helpful.
3. In the end how can I get it to leave cursor in the last empty cell of the first row, rather than the first one? In this case I put 1,1 intentionally, because I tried to put it in the end and failed. But I would like it in the end. :)

I would greatly appreciate anyone's help! Thanks a lot! :)

Here is the code:

```
Windows("Matlab Contours_Extracted_20170815.xlsx").Activate
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Matlab Contours consolidated.xlsx").Activate
Selection.ColumnWidth = 12.17
c = Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column + 1
Cells(1, c).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Matlab Contours_Extracted_20170815.xlsx").Activate
Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Activate
Columns("A:A").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Matlab Contours consolidated.xlsx").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Selection.ColumnWidth = 14.17
Rows("1:1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
With Selection
    .WrapText = True
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this :

```
Sub Matlab_Copy_Paste()

Dim Wb1 As Workbook
Dim Wb2 As Workbook
Dim i As Integer
Dim a As Integer

Set Wb1 = Workbooks("Matlab Contours_Extracted_20170815.xlsx") 'Adapt to your origin workbook
Set Wb2 = Workbooks("Matlab Contours consolidated.xlsm") 'Adapt to your destination workbook
a = 1

For i = 1 To Wb1.Sheets.Count
    Wb1.Sheets(i).Range("A1:A" & Wb1.Sheets(i).Range("A999999").End(xlUp).Row).Copy Wb2.Sheets(1).Cells(1, a)
    a = a + 1
Next i

Wb2.Sheets(1).Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Select

'Edit for transpose result
T1 = Wb2.Sheets(1).UsedRange
Wb2.Sheets(1).Cells.Clear
Wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(UBound(T1, 2), UBound(T1, 1)) = Application.Transpose(T1)
'End of edit for transpose result

End Sub
```

Not sure if you really wanted it pasted side by side tho...

Comment: Wow, thank you  so much!!! It looks so easy (and much less bulky than mine). And works like magic, that's exaclty what I needed!:) Can I ask you for a little addition? If I needed to transpose them after it's done, how would I do that? Keeping in mind that all these columns have different number of rows in them.

Comment: See edit for raw data. This will not keep any format or formulas from source.